# Rubyzip problems on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rubyzip

I'm using Rubyzip to unzip files that are uploaded by the user. The file contains a bunch of images, which are unpacked and put into a folder. This works fine on a mac, but on windows it won't unpack the zip file. Here's the model I use:

```
require "zip/zip"
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :image_file_name, :message => "Er is geen bestand bijgevoegd!"

  belongs_to :album

  has_attached_file :image, :styles => {
  :original => ["1024x1024>", :jpg],
  :medium => "300x250#",
  :thumb => "150x100#"
  }, :url => "/uploads/photos/:id/:style.:extension"

  def zip?
   image.content_type == "application/zip"
  end

  def save_photo
   if zip?
    extract_zip
    true
    else
    self.save
   end
  end

  def extract_zip
  Zip::ZipFile.foreach(image.queued_for_write[:original].path) do |entry|
   next if entry.name =~ /__MACOSX/ or entry.name =~ /\.DS_Store/ or !entry.file?
   filename = entry.name
   basename = File.basename(filename)

   tempfile = Tempfile.new(basename)
   tempfile.binmode
   tempfile.write(entry.get_input_stream.read)

  photo = Photo.create(:image => tempfile, :album_id => album_id)
end
end
end
```

Because it works fine on a mac I think it's the way Windows zips a file. maybe something to do with the header structure or something? Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Here is a thread from a couple of years back that may help: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2008/10/02/ruby-unzipping-a-file-using-rubyzip/

Comment: Thanx! I'll have a look at it!